# How do I sense that the serial monitor is started?

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom, reset

When starting the serial monitor in IDE I want to save important data to EEPROM before the Arduino Uno restarts. I do not have physical access to the Arduino so a "press button" solution does not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There is no way of detecting if the serial monitor is open or not.

However, you can [disable the automatic reset](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection) and provide some functionality in your code for saving data to EEPROM when prompted through a command entered on the serial monitor (if you now need to even save the data).

Comment: you did it again.  That is a very cool trick.  Thank you for teaching me that one.  I don't understand how the 120 Ohm value was figured out, but this is something I will put in my mental toolbox for sure.  Kudos.  Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is to store the data before the computer shuts down.

Here is what I did. 
 I am running a Mega in a car and using it for a lot of things.  The Mega receives its power from the ignition switch.  When the ignition switch it turned on, the Mega boots up.  In the "setup" section of the program, I set a digital output HIGH.  The digital output is tied to the coil of a relay.  One side of the relay is tied directly to the battery.  Once the relay is energized, the relay supplies power to the Mega.  I have a digital input tied to the power coming from the ignition switch through a resistor and a zener diode to clamp the voltage at 5 volts.  In the main program I monitor the input power digital input.  When I see the power go down,(ignition switch is turned off), I run a Shutdown program that stores all of the data I need stored to the EEProm.  Once that is done, I set the digital output LOW.  This de-energizes the relay and removes the power from the Mega.  If you push the reset button, that is a hardware reset and you lose your data.  If I want to reset the computer, I simply run the "Shutdown" routine. I can do that using a remote switch that drives a digital input.